# Simple TextToSpeech code

Tags: java, android

I want to make a simple `TextToSpeech` code. My code is here:

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
tts.speak("This is a Alert Application", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null,null);
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error:(100, 28) error: no suitable constructor found for TextToSpeech(MainActivity,MainActivity)
constructor TextToSpeech.TextToSpeech(Context,OnInitListener,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor TextToSpeech.TextToSpeech(Context,OnInitListener) is not applicable
(actual argument MainActivity cannot be converted to OnInitListener by method invocation conversion)
```

What am I missing? What i need to put in the code?

Comment: imple ments activty with OnInitListener

Comment: can you show us the full code ? starting from the class creation

Comment: I didn't create a class. I though this was enough. What am i missing?
I Just want to make a speak of "This is a Alert Application" when the application starts.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow of your thread to sleep and after sleep are you calling tts.speak(). if so, at that point looking at your code, the tts does not seem to be initialized and is null so will crash with an exception.

This code should prevent the exception, but if the initialization of the TTS engine takes too long, then you won't get it to say Loading. Also, I am guessing the 5 second (which is a really long time btw) sleep is to allow for it to get initialized?

### code

```
   public class mainj extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

   private TextToSpeech myTTS;
   // status check code
   private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.loadscreen);
   Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
   checkTTSIntent
     .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
   startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
   Thread logoTimer = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
                speakWords("loading");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //waiting for the sleep
            splash_wait()

        }

        finally {
            finish();
        }
      }

    };
     logoTimer.start();
   }

  // speak the user text
  private void speakWords(String speech) {

     // speak straight away
     if(myTTS != null)
     {
    myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
     }
    }

    // act on result of TTS data check
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
       if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
        // the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
        myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    } else {
        // no data - install it now
        Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
        installTTSIntent
                .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
        startActivity(installTTSIntent);
       }
   }
}

 // setup TTS
 public void onInit(int initStatus) {

 // check for successful instantiation
 if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
    if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
        myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
  } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

    private void splash_wait() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the activity as;

```
  public class AndroidTextToSpeech extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
```

Comment: All ready done it:
 `public class AndroidTextToSpeech extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
            TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            tts.speak("This is a Alert Application",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null,null);
} ` but now setLanguage and speak are in red and cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: Do you allow of your thread to sleep and after  sleep are you  calling tts.speak(). if so, at that point looking at your code, the tts does not seem to be initialized and is null so will crash with an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As in error output you have to initialize TextToSpeech object with valid parameter, as suggested, providing a `Context` and an `OnInitListener` objects.

This is a sample init (hope it helps):

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), 
  new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
      @Override
      public void onInit(int status) {
             if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                 tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
             }              
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{private int result = 0;
private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private EditText txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            speakOut();
        }
    });
}

// shutdown tts when activity destroy
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null)
    {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

// It will called before TTS started
@Override
public void onInit(int status)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // check status for TTS is initialized or not
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
    {
        // if TTS initialized than set language
        result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // you can set pitch level
        // tts.setSpeechRate(); //you can set speech speed rate

        // check language is supported or not
        // check language data is available or not
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Missing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // disable button
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            // if all is good than enable button convert text to speech
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }
}

// call this method to speak text
private void speakOut()
{
    String text = txtText.getText().toString();
    if (result != tts.setLanguage(Locale.US))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter right Words...... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        // speak given text
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

}

try above code

Comment: I tried this one but the app crashes when I write a sentence and then click in the speak button.

Comment: speak is deprecated. I want to try in Android ICS 4.0.1.

Comment: The problem is when i build the app there is no error but speak is writed with a line in the letters. I am using Android Studio in a a Virtual Machine and then make the apk and export the apk to the phone. I Can not see more errors.

Comment: is virtul device has speaker? than why u testing on it..!! try it on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code at the moment:

package com.example.texttospeech;

```
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

```
private int result = 0;
private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private EditText txtText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }
    });
}

// shutdown tts when activity destroy
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

// It will called before TTS started
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // check status for TTS is initialized or not
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        // if TTS initialized than set language
        result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        // tts.setPitch(5); // you can set pitch level
        // tts.setSpeechRate(); //you can set speech speed rate

        // check language is supported or not
        // check language data is available or not
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Missing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // disable button
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            // if all is good than enable button convert text to speech
            btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
    }
}

// call this method to speak text
private void speakOut() {
    String text = txtText.getText().toString();
    if (result != tts.setLanguage(Locale.US)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter right Words...... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        // speak given text
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

}

speak is deprecated